# Find the cell with a thick bottom border by rows

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to find the cell with a thick bottom border by rows.

The following code makes my whole workbook stop responding and I have to restart it.

```
Sub FindThiccBottomBorder()

Dim ws2 As Worksheet
Set ws2 = Sheets(2)

Dim brng As Range
Set brng = ws2.Range("C13")

start:
If brng.Borders(xlEdgeBottom).Weight = xlMedium Then
    On Error Resume Next
    brng.FormulaR1C1 = "found it!"
Else
    brng = brng.Offset(1)
    GoTo start
End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Start by removing the `On Error Resume Next`.  Then get rid of the `goto` and use a proper loop. After that, you can use the debugger to step through the code.

Comment: Your loop has no exit condition

Comment: @TimWilliams I thought the "loop" only loops until the brng.Borders(xlEdgeBottom).Weight = xlMedium is True. Is it not?

Comment: No, your code will continue "looping" because you never told it to stop. See my answer below.

Comment: You should read this https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask before you start ranting...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following is a better code to perform the same procedure.

```
Dim rngBottom As Range
Set rngBottom = Range("C13")

Do Until rngBottom.Borders(xlEdgeBottom).Weight = xlMedium
Set rngBottom = rngBottom.Offset(1)
Loop
rngBottom.Value = "found it!"
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim brng As Range
Dim Last_Row As Long

    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("My Sheet Name")    '<-- Replace this with your sheet name
    Set brng = ws.Range("C13")
    Last_Row = brng.Row + ws.UsedRange.Rows.Count - 1

    Do While brng.Row <= Last_Row
        If brng.Borders(xlEdgeBottom).Weight = xlMedium Then
            brng = "found it!"
            Exit Sub
        End If
        Set brng = brng.Offset(1)
    Loop
```

Some unsolicited advice:

- don't use "On Error Resume..." until you make your code working. It will hide your code problems;
- don't use "worksheet(number)" to assign worksheet. If the worksheet number changes, your code will fail. Use the worksheet name instead;
- Don't use GoTo. It's a bad coding style, and you almost never need it;

Comment: Thanks for your input. Your code however only works if the cell with the xlEdgeBottom border (or the rows after that) is a non-blank cell. I want the code to work even with blank cells. Is it possible to achieve this? Thanks again for your advice. I will definitely take note.

Answer (score -1):

This is the answer to my initial question.

```
Sub FindThiccBottomBorder()

Dim ws2 As Worksheet
Set ws2 = Sheets("Sheet2")

Dim brng As Range
Set brng = ws2.Range("C13")

start:
If brng.Borders(xlEdgeBottom).Weight = xlMedium Then
    brng.FormulaR1C1 = "found it!"
    Exit Sub
Else
End If

set brng = brng.Offset(1)
GoTo start

End Sub
```

Comment: In this piece of code you really don't need the `Else`, since you're not doing anything anyway. Still not looping properly like in RADO's answer. Other than that it'll work. GoTo is a construction that was necessary back in the early days of Basic, when proper error handling constructions weren't implemented.

Comment: Yes if the person who keeps downvoting my stuff tell me why, so that I can learn from your response, that'd be great. Don't just downvote and leave. It's helping no one.